# Routing Error, get action in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

This is my first custom route, any help would be appreciated.

The error upon visting /quotes/new

```
No route matches {:controller=>"QuotesController", :action=>"getdata"}
```

My form:

```
<%= f.input :make, collection: clothing_types, label: 'Thread Type', remote: true,
 :'data-url' => url_for( :controller => 'QuotesController', :action => 'getdata'), 
 :'data-type' => 'json', input_html: {class: "select_make"} %>
```

(I've tried changing 'QuotesController' to just 'Quotes', or 'quotes_controller' and they just change the wording in the error)

Routes.rb

```
get 'quotes/getdata' => 'quotes#new'
```

quotes_controller.rb

```
def getdata
  @make = params[:make]
  @clothes = Product.where(:item_make => @make).all
  render :json => @clothes.map{|c| [c.id, c.name]}
end
```

When I run rake routes, I see

```
quotes_getdata GET    /quotes/getdata(.:format)       quotes#new
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `get 'quotes/getdata' => 'quotes#new'` to `get 'quotes/getdata' => 'quotes#getdata'`.
And on the form `url_for( :controller => 'QuotesController', :action => 'getdata')` to `url_for( :controller => 'quotes', :action => 'getdata')`

Additionally, you can improve your view code by declaring a named_route like this:

```
'quotes/getdata' => 'quotes#new', as: :quotes_getdata
```

And the form:

```
<%= f.input :make, collection: clothing_types, label: 'Thread Type', remote: true,
:'data-url' => quotes_getdata_path, :'data-type' => 'json', input_html: {class: "select_make"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route directs `quotes/getdata` to the `new` action of `QuotesController`. When you call `url_for`, it doesn't find a route mapping to a `getdata` action of `QuotesController`.

All you have to do is modify your `url_for` parameters like so:

```rb
url_for(controller: 'quotes', action: 'new')
```

The above will generate `http://.../quotes/getdata` as desired.

Alternatively, you could call `quotes_getdata_url` in place of `url_for`.

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

```
url_for(controller: :quotes, action: :getdata)
```

and more important:

is this form sent via GET? - if not yu should adopt your routes to response also to POST requests.